# get response from php remote server node js POST

Tags: php, node.js, electron

i am pretty new to node js and want to send a json to a php remote server via node js and get a json back as response, tried googling and stackoverflow too but could not find anything useful. need help for both sides

Comment: could not achieve anything so i need a test sample from start

Comment: Please go read [ask]. We are not here to help you find code examples, if you need those, you need to go find them yourself or ask elsewhere.

Comment: Look up how to do an AJAX request in Node ;-)

Comment: @delboy1978uk  thanks for the guide, my problem solved by a nice developer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you all for reading this , my problem is solved by a nice guy who helped alot.